# How to migrate dnx command to net core cli

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have a custom command-project for asp.net 5, such as the entity framework commands.

When port all projects to aspnetcore rc2, try to replace "commands" section of project.json to "tools", but when run cucstom tool in "dotnet-" get "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '...nuget\packages.tools\MyProject.Tools'."

what am I doing wrong?

Update: I create nuget pkg, local storage for my pkg and install my "tools project" to my solution via nuget. Now my tools work fine. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Is the command project in the same solution as the other project?

Comment: I think you already have tried to add your tools to the local project collection (meaning the one `dotnet build` would actually build). If yes and it still does not work, I recommend to file an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/cli. I think the platform should have it.

Comment: There is no easier method currently. I've raised an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3239) relating to this very issue. The currently methodology is to pack and restore, which is a horrible development experience - as well as not supporting debugging and next to no documentation yet.